# Array split task: based on values and custom types

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-science

There are two 2-D `ndarray`s A and B.

`A` contains panel values for a feature, rows represents days, columns are different regions. There are ~3000 columns and ~5000 rows in A. Such as

```
A = array([[ 3.53, 3.56, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan], # day 1 data
   [-4.91, -2.54, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan], # day 2 data
   [-6.31, -3.39, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan], # day 3 data, etc
   ..., 
   [ 0.  , -3.41, nan, ..., 12.69, 2.32, nan],
   [-2.74, -4.14, nan, ..., -8.63, -1.45, nan],
   [-1.74, -7.45, nan, ..., 0.68, -6.52, nan]])
```

`B` contains the type of each value corresponding in A. There are around 30 types in total. Such as

```
B = array([[  'A', 'B', nan, ..., nan, nan, nan], # day 1 type
           [  'A', 'A', nan, ..., nan, nan, nan], # day 2 type, etc
           ...,
           [  'D', 'E', nan, ..., 'I', 'D', nan],
           [  'X', 'Y', nan, ..., 'O', 'S', nan]])
```

The goal is for each day (row), the regions should be split into 10 groups based on values (group 10 > group 9 ...). And for each group, the weight of each type should be equal to `total number of the type in the row / 10`. For example,

```
 day 1: 
       # of A: 35    -->  weight of A in each group: 3.5
       # of B: 33    -->  weight of B in each group: 3.3
       ...
       # of Z: 6     -->  weight of Z in each group: 0.6
```

And the result should be something like

```
weight_group_1 = array([[  1,  1,  nan, ..., 0.5, ..., 1, ..., nan, nan, nan]
# And the sum of each group's weights should be equal, if all steps correct.
weight_group_2 = array([[  0,  0,  nan, ..., 1, ..., 0.3, ..., nan, nan, nan]
and so on
```

Are there any efficient algorithms to achieve this? Please help, thanks in advance!